# How do I install clang 18 on Ubuntu?

Tags: apt, clang

software I need to use is requiring clang 18 to be installed on my computer:

`em++: warning: LLVM version for clang executable "/usr/bin/clang" appears incorrect (seeing "14.0", expected "18") [-Wversion-check]`

After little bit of searching I've learned I should use the command `sudo apt install clang-18`
Running that has given me `E: Unable to locate package clang-18`.

The software is requiring clang 18 but package manager can't find it.
Do I need to include third party repository or something ? I'm on Ubuntu 22.04 .

Thank you for assistance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [this guide](https://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2023/09/how-to-install-clang-17-or-16-in-ubuntu-22-04-20-04/) you can install Clang 18.

In brief, there are 3 steps:

1. Download the Automatic Installation Script using the Terminal -

   ```
   wget https://apt.llvm.org/llvm.sh
   ```

   After Downloading, add executable permission by running this command -

   ```
   chmod u+x llvm.sh
   ```
2. Use the script to install Clang:

   ```
   sudo ./llvm.sh 18
   ```

   During the process, it will ask to hit Enter to confirm adding the apt repository. Then, you may just wait until the process done.
3. Verify using the following code:

   ```
   clang-18 --version
   ```

   and/or locate clang-18 to verify.